# Evaluating an integral with a $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ in it ; How to solve it?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

Problem:

Perform the following integration:
$$ \int \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} \,\, dx $$
Answer:

Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \sqrt{ 1 + \dfrac{1}{x^2} }  \,\, dx
\end{align*}
Now, I will try letting $ x = -\cot \theta $. We have:
\begin{align*}
dx &= -\csc^2 \theta \,\, d\theta \\
I &= \int ( -\csc^2 \theta ) \sqrt{ 1 + \tan^2 \theta } \,\, d\theta \\
I &= \int ( -\csc^2 \theta ) \sqrt{ \sec^2 \theta } \,\, d\theta \\
I &= \int - \dfrac{1}{ \cos \theta \sin^2 \theta } \,\, d\theta
\end{align*}
Now, I feel stuck. I will try a different approach. I will use integration by parts
with $u = \dfrac{ \sqrt{x^2+1} } {x}$ and $dv = dx$. We have:
\begin{align*}
du &= \dfrac{ x(2x)(x^2+1)^{\dfrac{-1}{2}} - \sqrt{x^2+1}   } { x^2 } \,\, dx \\
\end{align*}
I do not think integration by parts is going to work. What is the right way to evaluate this integral?

Comment: One of the standard substitutions would be $x=\sinh t$, when $\sqrt{x^2+1}=\cosh t$, and $dx=\cosh t\,dt$. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{x^2+1}=u^2$, $x^2=u^2-1$, $x=\sqrt{u^2-1}$, $dx=\frac{2udu}{2\sqrt{u^2-1}}$.

Then
$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}dx}{x}=\int \frac{\sqrt{u^2}\times 2udu}{\sqrt{u^2-1} \times 2\sqrt{u^2-1}}=\int \frac{u^2 du}{u^2-1}=\int \frac{u^2-1+1}{u^2-1}du=\int du +\int \frac{du}{u^2-1}.$

This is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Try $x=\tan\theta$ instead. Then the integrand becomes $(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\csc\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ which is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Continue from where you are stuck:
$$I=\int -\frac{1}{\cos u \sin^2 u}\mathrm{d}u=-\int\frac{\sin^2u+\cos^2 u}{\cos u \sin^2 u}\mathrm{d}u =-\int \sec u \mathrm{d}u -\int\frac{\cos u}{\sin^2 u} \mathrm{d}u $$
and the last two integrals are elementary.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} d x 
= & \int \frac{x^2+1}{x \sqrt{x^2+1}} d x \\
= & \int \frac{x^2+1}{x^2} d\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right) \\
= & \int\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) d\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right) \\
= & \sqrt{x^2+1}+\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)^2-1} \\
= & \sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$